# SQL to get median of column from multiple tables, grouped by user id

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, how would one get the median of a certain column, in my case "liked_count", aggregated across multiple tables, and group them by another column, in my case "creator_id"?

Just so I'm sure I'm being clear here; I have multiple tables with columns "liked_count" and "creator_id", I'd like to get the median liked_count for each creator across all tables, not each table individually.

I can get the average, with AVG(), but there seems to be no median function.

```
select a.creator_id, avg(a.liked_count) as average
from (
select creator_id, liked_count from type1
union select creator_id, liked_count from type2
union select creator_id, liked_count from type3
union select creator_id, liked_count from type4
union select creator_id, liked_count from type5
) a group by a.creator_id order by average desc, a.creator_id desc limit 10
```

Edit: I should add that I need the entire thing to be on the MySQL server, without returning the data to my web server, because the data sets need to scale into the millions, this function needs to be run often (and quickly (at least under 100ms, sub 50 would be better) and I need to be able to limit. As such I've added a limit to my AVG example; I need that, but for median.

Comment: There's no function, but there is a standard formula

Answer (score 0):

At least as far as I know, there is no median function.

There are probably better ways to do it, but when I've needed it, I've taken the top count/2+1 items when ordered by the column in question, then taken the bottom one of that.

For my purposes that was close enough, but for a truly accurate median, you need to check if the count is even, and if so get the bottom two (the two middle items), and average their values.